# getting UNDEFINED when trying to return json from service layer to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When i try to return data from function in service layer to controller layer i get "undefined".

On the other hand, when I implement the function in the controller everything works fine.

Service Function:
[image]

Controller Function:
[image]

The error from POSTMAN:
[image]

When I implement the function just in the controller everything works fine and i get the data:

Controller Function:
[image]

POSTMAN Result:
[image]

Comment: The function `getStockFundsByName` isn't returning anything. (also, post code, not images of code)

Comment: The getStockFundsByName function returns data. So what is the problem?

Comment: @Maoragai No it does not. A callback *within* the function does, but not the function itself. You forgot `return fetch(...)`. You can find details in the duplicate question.

Comment: I do not believe, I didn't notice.  
Thank you so much !